# Can't run Docker in my VPS ( virtuozzo 7 container )

Tags: docker, containers, virtuozzo

i can't run docker ... what that mean.
i have a VPS centos 7 in ( virtuozzo 7 container )
i'm try to run docker " docker run hello-world"
but the screen was freeze and go blank 
when i try dockerd the result is

```
# dockerd
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 2703
WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
WARN[0001] failed to rename /var/lib/docker/tmp for background deletion: %!s(<nil>). Deleting synchronously
ERRO[0001] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.
ERRO[0001] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.
INFO[0001] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support oom control
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support memory swappiness
WARN[0001] Your kernel does not support kernel memory limit
WARN[0001] mountpoint for pids not found
INFO[0001] Loading containers: start.
WARN[0001] Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: ``, error: exit status 1
WARN[0001] Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: ``, error: exit status 1
WARN[0001] Could not load necessary modules for Conntrack: Running modprobe nf_conntrack failed with message: ``, error: exit status 1
INFO[0001] Removing stale sandbox 088326295ef4709608c127eb1e6a770b8fcfe7988f086c6fb87b292b829051c6 (482232da51cc4160328c53e33b2d755e97d17d72828c792533ec1c6b9f38300b)
INFO[0001] Removing stale endpoint amazing_keller (f795d761e9d6f540a5e5f79e692057c4aa6336bdca99421f828387b4ea2f5ad5)
INFO[0001] Fixing inconsistent endpoint_cnt for network bridge. Expected=0, Actual=1
INFO[0001] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address
INFO[0001] Loading containers: done.
INFO[0001] Daemon has completed initialization
INFO[0001] Docker daemon                                 commit=89658be graphdriver=vfs version=17.05.0-ce
INFO[0001] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
```

and my kernel is

```
#uname -a
Linux 3.10.0-042stab126.1 #1 SMP Wed Nov 15 20:14:46 MSK 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

can any one help ?

Comment: What does `docker info` say?

Answer (score 0):

```
#docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: vfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9048e5e50717ea4497b757314bad98ea3763c145
runc version: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228
init version: 949e6fa
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-042stab126.1
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1GiB
ID: YJC2:QNRL:ZAXH:TCL3:F7IS:75RM:3H35:V75N:T2WS:IPSJ:I6P3:4WUN
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.0/8,docker-registry.somecorporation.com
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
```

Comment: Any one help me ?

Comment: It looks like docker is running, the only issue I see is that you are using the vfs storage driver, that will not work well.  From the errors about the overlay storage driver not being available, and the output of your uname command, I would guess that you are on a modified virtuozzo 6 kernel which was not built with overlay functionality.  You should double check with your host if you are actually using Virtuozzo 7 or if they otherwise have overlay capability available in your container.